# Adding virtual host changes DocumentRoot in httpd.conf

Tags: apache

In my httpd.conf there is,

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

When I add an index.php in this directory and give `http://localhost`, it works OK.

But now I add a virtual host in httpd.conf,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/eric/Devel/Web
    ServerName web
</VirtualHost>
```

When I give `http://localhost`, the document root is the one in web, /home/eric/Devel/Web and the index.php in there is the server.This is what I do not understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using name-based virtual hosts, in which case the virtual host named first in the configuration becomes the default. See the remark in [the httpd docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using):

> **Main host goes away**
>
> If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must
>   also create a  block for the existing host. The
>   ServerName and DocumentRoot included in this virtual host should be
>   the same as the global ServerName and DocumentRoot. List this virtual
>   host first in the configuration file so that it will act as the
>   default host.